# Drag and Drop in Kivymd List

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I am building a simple shopping list app using KivyMD. I want be able to reorder items on the list using intuitive drag and drop. How can this be achieved? I am using OneLineIconListItem inside of MDList inside of ScrollView.

I do not care if draging does work with a specific handle added to the items or by long pressing.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.